# Considering Highest Peak Curve From Two Sets of Data Points

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I have two columns which would correspond to x and y-axis in which I will be eventually graphing that sets of data points to a curve like graph.

The problem is that based on the nature of the datapoints, when graphing it, I end up having two peaks however, I want to pick only the highest peak when graphing and discard the lowest peak(s) (not the highest point but the entire the highest peak graphed).

Is there away to do that in Python? I don't show the codes here because I am not sure how to do the coding at all.

Here is the datapoints (input) as well as the graph!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "pick only the highest peak when graphing and discard the lowest peak(s)" mean? Say you've found the highest peak in the graph. What exactly is the next step you'd like to do?

Comment: The input is a set of data points (x,y), when I graphed, I get multiple peaks. However, I want only the graph to have a single and highest peak which is what the output is, the graph of the highest peak from data points and this is what I want! thanks

Comment: Could you attach the screenshot of the plots obtained? It's really impossible to reproduce the problem without the adequate data/output.

Comment: Did that, please check, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy` argrelextrema to get all the peaks, work out the maximum and then build up a mask array for the peak you want to plot. This will give you full control based on your data, using things like mincutoff to work out what determines a separate peak,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup and plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,6.14,7.04,5.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16.58,60.06,99.58,100,50,0.,0.,0.])
x = np.linspace(3.92,161,y.size)
ax[0].plot(x,y)

#get peaks
peaks_indx = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)[0]
peaks = y[peaks_indx]
ax[0].plot(x[peaks_indx],y[peaks_indx],'o')

#Get maxpeak
maxpeak = 0.
for p in peaks_indx:
    print(p)
    if y[p] > maxpeak:
        maxpeak = y[p]
        maxpeak_indx = p

#Get mask of data around maxpeak to plot
mincutoff = 0.
indx_to_plot = np.zeros(y.size, dtype=bool)
for i in range(maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx-i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
        break

for i in range(y.size-maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx+i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
        break
ax[1].plot(x[indx_to_plot],y[indx_to_plot])
plt.show()
```

The result is then,

[image]

UPDATE: Code to plot only the largest peak.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup and plot data
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,6.14,7.04,5.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,16.58,60.06,99.58,100,50,0.,0.,0.])
x = np.linspace(3.92,161,y.size)

#get peaks
peaks_indx = argrelextrema(y, np.greater)[0]
peaks = y[peaks_indx]

#Get maxpeak
maxpeak = 0.
for p in peaks_indx:
    print(p)
    if y[p] > maxpeak:
        maxpeak = y[p]
        maxpeak_indx = p

#Get mask of data around maxpeak to plot
mincutoff = 0.
indx_to_plot = np.zeros(y.size, dtype=bool)
for i in range(maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx-i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx-i] = True
        break

for i in range(y.size-maxpeak_indx):
    if y[maxpeak_indx+i] > mincutoff:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
    else:
        indx_to_plot[maxpeak_indx+i] = True
        break

#Plot just the highest peak
plt.plot(x[indx_to_plot],y[indx_to_plot])
plt.show()
```

I would still suggest plotting both peaks to ensure the algorithm is working correctly... I think you will find that identifying an arbitrary peak is probably not always trivial with messy data.

Comment: why the second figure doesn't start from y = 0 instead of y starting around 17?

Comment: It's just a result of the if condition greater than `mincutoff=0.`. I've changed to add the first zero values to the plot. In practice, I'd assume the data would not always cleanly go to zero so stopping at mincutoff is best.

Comment: Thanks, how one can control the display of the graph, I mean there are two graphs presented, how can I only display the right graph graph?

Comment: Also would you kindly explain what you did for the codes #Setup and plot data, I am not clear of what did you do at the code ?

Comment: The setup and plot section creates a figure and you then add plots to it. The `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)` sets up a figure handle `fig` with two axes stored in a tuple `ax` (`ax[0]` and `ax[1]`) and then `ax[0].plot` adds the plots. You can simply plot the single peak with `plt.plot(x[indx_to_plot],y[indx_to_plot])` then `plt.show()` and delete all other calls to plot. Check out a matplotlib tutorial for more information (http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, if for instance wants to modify and my x,y values in your codes, what those variables are ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... `x` and `y` can be whatever you want, I've just manually typed some values into an array in my code above. It was based on your data but I needed to add a few more points because the two peak graph you showed clearly doesn't agree with the data in your table.

Comment: Ok make sense. Your output shows two graphs, one graph has two peaks in it and the other graph has only one peak which the highest peak. I want only the highest peak graph , the second graph and not the first resulted graph. I tried modifying several things in the code but wasn't successful!

Comment: I've updated to plot just a single peak, although I think you should take care to ensure it is working correctly...